# printing by calling a function (pass by value) in C

Tags: c, function

I am trying a write a program that prints a pyramid by calling a function (pass by value and not pass by address).

Well, the function is just supposed to run a for loop to print the pyramid but the actual printing statement is written in the main. The rest of the program seems fine but there is an error in the function call.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? It is the syntax that I am having trouble with. The error is **"argument of type void is incompatible with parameter type of 'constant char*'**"

```
#include<stdio.h>

void pyramid(int);              //function declaration

int main()
{
    int r1;
    printf("Enter the number of rows you would like printed:");
    scanf("%d",&r1);
    printf(pyramid(r1));        //function call
    return 0;
}
void pyramid(int r2)            //function definition
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=r2;i>=1;i--)
    {
        for(j=r2;j<=i;j--)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are using `printf` to call function. You can directly call `pyramid(r1);`

Comment: @Himanshu thanks. that works well. but just to reassure myself, printf cannot be used to call a function?

Comment: As function is returning no value, so need to call it in `printf`. here you are using `void` type function if it is `int` or `char` type then you can print its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void pyramid(int);              //function declaration
```

Here the function pyramid will not return any value,

**But you are expecting it to return a value in the below statement**

> `printf(pyramid(r1));        //function call`

Also this program would run in to an infinite loop,
Here:

```
for(i=r2;i>=1;i--)
{
    for(j=r2;j<=i;j--) //**j will always be less than i**
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I corrected the logic for infinite loop now. Always seem to get nested loops confused. If I type `printf(pyramid(r1));` how am i expecting it to return a value, I thought I am just passing a original argument. Can you please elaborate? I think I am misunderstanding passing a value and returning a value.

Comment: You are passing the argument r1 to pyramid() by value. Also as pyramid() has the return type void, which is similar to writing printf(void);

Answer (score 1):

printf's prototype is

```
int printf(const char *restrict format, ...);
```

But you are trying to pass `void` to it by calling `printf(pyramid(r1));`. Call function directly like `pyramid(r1);` instead of  `printf(pyramid(r1));`.